# Perform a INSERT .. SELECT in MySQL with derived tables

Tags: mysql, select, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert the results from a join query into another table.

```
INSERT INTO temp(
SELECT b.id, b.number, b.attempt FROM(
SELECT number FROM duplicate_numbers)a 
JOIN calls b ON b.number=a.number));
```

The join query on its own without the INSERT INTO clause works fine and returns a dataset. But the above query gives SQL syntax error

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT b.id

Comment: There are too many right parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Change query syntax like this:

```
CREATE TABLE temp (`id` int, `number` int, `attempt` int);

INSERT INTO temp (`id`, `number`, `attempt`)
SELECT b.id, b.number, b.attempt FROM (
  SELECT number FROM duplicate_numbers
) a 
JOIN calls b ON b.number=a.number
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24f9f

Comment: @Prashan Same error? `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT b.id` ?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 4

Comment: @Prashan Is `temp` table empty? Otherwise need to run an `UPDATE` statement

Comment: temp table is empty

Comment: @Prashan what is the version on MySql?

Comment: @Prashan try the `SELECT INTO` statement added to the answer above

Comment: Version is 5.1.73

Comment: Added SELECT INTO. Gives error ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: temp

Comment: @Prashan I have added a working demo link in the answer. Had to create the `temp` table first.

Comment: It worked only when I replaced `CREATE TABLE temp` with `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp`

Comment: @Prashan oh ok. I guess table creation permissions are not available in the current database which is why adding TEMPORARY keyword was needed.